# Drupal 7 Exposed Filter Display Text

Tags: views

I have an exposed filter in drupal, but some text is not displaying as expected. One list displays exactly as I want and that is the Acoustic Guitars as shown in the picture, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why the other filters are not displaying like the Acoustic Guitars. Here is the picture, does anyone know what settings I would need to change to get this to display the description instead of the category like the Acoustic Guitars list?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'ts in your content type. You might have mistaken the label with the value, or not used the label at all. Open the content type, edit each field and change the allowed values as described above the textarea.

If I'm not mistaken it is

```
Label|value
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this via the admin panels?

Comment: `/admin/structure/types` and then choose the content type, which contains the wrong fields. Hit the manage fields link and then edit all fields. If you can't see the manage fields link, make sure the `fields ui` module is enabled.